# Have i found a compiler bug or do I seriously misunderstand the C++ Standard in regard to non-local static variable initialization?

Tags: c++

I am maintaining an embedded application running on an old Analog Devices DSP (ADSP-2191). We are stuck with their VisualDSP++ 3.5 Toolchain which according to their documentation adheres to the C++98 standard with some (minor) exceptions and extensions.

My question is regarding a very primitive case of, what i believe to be, a compiler bug during initialization of non-local static (global) variables. I created a simple test-case to show the issue:

```cpp
int direct_init_var = 0xFEED;
int direct_init_array[ 4 ] = { 0xDE, 0xCA, 0xFB, 0xAD };
int deref_init_var = direct_init_array[ 0 ];

int main( void )
{
  return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand it, this should pose no problem and `deref_init_var` shall be initialized to the value `0xDE`. The initialization may happen after prior zero-init and, in newer standards, maybe even after the first call to `main()` but before any odr-use of the variable.
From the C++98 Standard:

> Objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) shall be zero-initialized (8.5) before any other initialization takes place. A reference with static storage duration and an object of POD type with static storage duration can be initialized with a constant expression (5.19); this is called constant initialization. Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization.

Ok, so I had a look at the assembly the compiler generated and I believe here is where the problem lies. This snippet shows the symbols for the declared and initialized variables:

```
    .section/data data1;

    .align 1;
_direct_init_var:
    .global _direct_init_var;
    .type _direct_init_var,STT_OBJECT;
    .var = 0xFEED;
._direct_init_var.end:
    .align 1;
_direct_init_array:
    .global _direct_init_array;
    .type _direct_init_array,STT_OBJECT;
    .var = 0x00DE,0x00CA,0x00FB,0x00AD;
._direct_init_array.end:
    .align 1;
    .global _deref_init_var;
    .type _deref_init_var,STT_OBJECT;
    .var _deref_init_var[1];
._deref_init_var.end:
```

For me, this seems to be malformed. The start symbol of `_deref_init_var` is not even defined and it appears to reference itself for initialization. I would have expected the following output:

```
    .section/data data1;

    .align 1;
_direct_init_var:
    .global _direct_init_var;
    .type _direct_init_var,STT_OBJECT;
    .var = 0xFEED;
._direct_init_var.end:
    .align 1;
_direct_init_array:
    .global _direct_init_array;
    .type _direct_init_array,STT_OBJECT;
    .var = 0x00DE,0x00CA,0x00FB,0x00AD;
._direct_init_array.end:
    .align 1;
_deref_init_var:
    .global _deref_init_var;
    .type _deref_init_var,STT_OBJECT;
    .var _direct_init_array[0];
._deref_init_var.end:
```

Or even direct expansion of the initialization value:

```
_deref_init_var:
    .global _deref_init_var;
    .type _deref_init_var,STT_OBJECT;
    .var = 0x00DE;
._deref_init_var.end:
```

When I compile this program with MSVC (within a test-harness we use for debugging) I get this output for the variable in question:

```
?deref_init_var@@3FA DW DEH             ; deref_init_var
```

Am I wrong in blaming the VisualDSP++ compiler here?
Thanks in advance, any input is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I think I overlooked a major problem in the whole system design. The application in question is loaded during runtime by an "OS" that calls certain functions within the application through a jump-table. I will have to investigate a bit, but i believe there is no dynamic initialization happening at all. Thanks for your comments, I totally misinterpreted what was happening.

Comment: Can you change the `main` to `main() { return deref_init_var ; }` and inspect actual side effects (ie. if the program return value is equal to 0xDE))? Maybe the variable initialization was moved elsewhere by the compiler, could it be? | Ex. inspect gcc [__static_initialization_and_destruction_0](https://godbolt.org/z/XM7fW_). The `int deref_init_var = direct_init_array[ 0 ];` is like calling `int()` constructor.

Comment: It is likely that `deref_init_var` is put into the `bss` section, and get dynamically initialized.

Comment: This should not be surprising since initialization is not performed with a constant expression.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, in fact, the problem was first discovered because the program behaved incorrectly on the target hardware but passed all tests when compiled in the test environment. The initialization is in fact never happening. When compiling with MSVC and optimizations off, the compiler generates a dynamic initializer instead which is called later.

Comment: Does you embedded target properly calls other object constructors with static storage duration? `class test { test() { printf("Hello world!"); } }; test t; int main() {}` ? Maybe you use linker that doesn't call C++ constructors properly? Maybe grab a debugger and inspect instruction by instruction what is hapenning (from the entrypoint, reset vector or what you have there). In the program you posted, all variables may be optimized out, there is no reason to initialize anything, the program has no side effects.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it seems malformed*"? What happens in the final application, does it work or not?

Comment: @KamilCuk Good points.  Unfortunately I cannot debug the program on target at the moment. What i found however, is that the compiler does in fact generate a dynamic initializer, which I overlooked at first, sorry:

`___sti___8_Main_cpp_fa470ff0:
  RTS (DB);
//  line ".\Source\Main.cpp":3
  SI = DM(ADDRESS(_direct_init_array));
  DM(ADDRESS(_deref_init_var)) = SI;`

Maybe the dynamic initialization is not called correctly. I will investigate further. Thank you very much for your ideas.

Comment: You need to debug the program on target before coming to any conclusions (and before asking!). The standard describes program _behaviour_, not specifics about compiled assembly.